# Create python exe in windows with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an executable from a python script that I created, but I'm stuck

I installed Python 3.9 x64 for windows and pyinstaller, following different tutorials, but nothing works to me. The initial tutorial was this (I followed others similiars to this too):

https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

next, when I was trying to create the .exe with the command: `pyinstaller name_archive.py`
I got the next error:

```
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

for that problem, I found some solution here:

https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/python/pyinstaller-no-se-reconoce-como-comando-interno-o-externo/834789072/

I added to the Environment Variables, to PATH, in User Variables and System Variable both, the next dir:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts

Now, running again the command: `pyinstaller name_archive.py` in the cmd and with the route of the archive (`C:\Users\User\Desktop\K1>pyinstaller name_arhive.py`) gives this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" name_archive.py': The system can't find the specified file
```

I looked for the problem widely in the web, but I couldn't find any helpful information, even in the pyinstaller website... (https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/)

Please help, I tried anything for the last four hours and nothing results... lol

Comment: Try running your command with the full path to your file. >pyinstaller C:/full/path/to/name_archive.py

Comment: Now, running again the command: pyinstaller name_archive.py in the cmd and with the route of the archive (C:\Users\User\Desktop\K1>pyinstaller name_arhive.py) gives this error: 'Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" name_archive.py': The system can't find the specified file'

Comment: Can you post for full command here?